Series Equality Involving Cubic Terms and Exponential Growth
I'm currently working on a mathematical problem and need some help proving an equality involving two infinite series. The goal is to prove the following equality
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{12}{(n^3-n)3^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{8}{n3^n} - 3.
$$
I've been trying to manipulate the series and apply different techniques: integrating power series and division into partial fractions, however I'm stuck (probably the first approach is a wrong way).

$n^3-n=(n-1)n(n+1)$, so maybe you can use partial fractions on $(n^3-n)^{-1}=A(n+1)^{-1}+Bn^{-1}+C(n-1)^{-1}$

@GerryMyerson, I tried. The series on the LHS can be rewritten nicely, but I'm still stuck. No terms cancel or anything.

Why don't you write out what you got, maybe someone will see how to continue from there.

The partial fractions method will work.
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{12}{(n^3-n)3^n}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{6}{(n-1)3^n}+ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{-12}{n3^n}+ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{6}{(n+1)3^n}.$$
Now put the sums into the form on the right hand side.
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{6}{(n-1)3^n}= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(n-1)3^{n-1}}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n3^n}$$ The last equal follows from $n-1=1$ when $n=2$, $n-1=2$ when $n=3$, etc.
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{-12}{n3^n}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-12}{n3^n}+\frac{12}{3} $$
When changing from $\sum_{n=2}$ to $\sum_{n=1}$ you added in an extra term so have to subtract that.
I will leave the third sum for you. If you don’t get the $8$ in the numerator and the $-3$, then the problem is not correct.

Works just fine, thanks Steen!
